# Namespaces with multiple cyclic inclusion

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, include, forward-declaration

I've 3 classes that belong to a namespace "MyNS". "A" uses the "B" and "C", while both "B" and "C" use "A". Here are the structure of my headers:

```
//mynamespace.h
#ifndef SOMENAMESPACE_H
#define SOMENAMESPACE_H
namespace MyNS {
     class A;
     class B;
     class C;
}
#endif
/*******************************************************/
//A.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "mynamespace.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

class MyNS::A {
    ..
    MyNS::B someMethod(args);
    MyNS::C someMethod2(args);
    ..
};
#endif
/*******************************************************/
//B.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "mynamespace.h"
#include "A.h"

class MyNS::B {
    ..
    MyNS::A *someMember;
    ..
};
#endif
/*******************************************************/
//C.h
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#include "mynamespace.h"
#include "A.h"

class MyNS::C {
    ..
    MyNS::A *someMember;
    ..
};
#endif
```

Each  of the classes has a C++ source file that includes the line:

```
using namespace MyNS;
```

The compiler is stopped by the B.h header guards, that's why I get an "incomplete type 'class B'" error in A::someMethod(args).

I know I could have included all the class definitions inside "mynamespace.h", but the classes are long which made my header file bloated, that's why I had to separate them like this.

How can I make this code work with separate header files ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to get this code working with no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is using [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration). Do not include `A.h` in  `C.h` and `B.h`. Only actually perform `#include "A.h"` in  `B.cpp` and `C.cpp`. The forward declaration in the namespace should be enough.

```
//mynamespace.h
#ifndef SOMENAMESPACE_H
#define SOMENAMESPACE_H
namespace MyNS {
     class A;
     class B;
     class C;
}
#endif
/*******************************************************/
//A.h
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "mynamespace.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

class MyNS::A {
    ..
    MyNS::B someMethod(args);
    MyNS::C someMethod2(args);
    ..
};
#endif
/*******************************************************/
//B.h
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "mynamespace.h"

class MyNS::B {
    ..
    MyNS::A *someMember;
    ..
};
#endif
/*******************************************************/
//C.h
#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

#include "mynamespace.h"

class MyNS::C {
    ..
    MyNS::A *someMember;
    ..
};
#endif
```

Comment: Where are the functions defined? Define the functions in the cpp files. The cpp file will perform the include.

Comment: I also edited my answer a bit so that you can actually use B and C in A.h but you cant use A in B.h and C.h.